# Reading a log file from given path using logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

```
input 
{
  file 
  {
    path => ["D:/logstash-2.3.4/temp/logs/localhost_access_log.2016-08-24.log"]
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter 
{
  date 
  {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output 
{
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Now after running logstash i am unable to see any output on logstash command window. That is the logs inside a give file are not fetching.

some of the sample logs in my localhost_access_log.2016-08-24 log file are below:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2016:10:07:54 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452    
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [24/Aug/2016:10:08:09 +0530] "GET /Migration/firstpage.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 1040    
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2016:10:08:39 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452    
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [24/Aug/2016:10:08:41 +0530] "GET /Migration/firstpage.jsp HTTP/1.1" 500 3750    
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [24/Aug/2016:10:09:38 +0530] "GET /Mortgage/faces/NewFile.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 1046
```

Is there any problem with the input code or date filter code?
Can anyone help me where i am committing mistake?

Comment: Your date filter is useless since the field `timestamp` does not exist. You'll have first to extract the date from your log line in a timestamp field, using for example the grok filter with the COMMONAPACHELOG pattern. But I don't know why you don't have any output.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try keeping the `stdout {}` empty as this within your `output` section of your conf file in order to check the output from your `logstash` console?

As @baudsp mentioned, it's better to use `grok` filter when you're dealing with log files. Something like this:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
}
```

Source: [Parsing Logs with Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html)